# Opentelemetry collector gives "partialSuccess": {} response

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, open-telemetry, telemetry

I have an opentelemetry collector contrib (0.69.0) installed inside OpenShift container and I want to export my traces to Datadog. I have an http endpoint URL exposed for my Collector service and I can ping it, however when I want to send in some sample trace from Postman to test the connection, I get the following response:

request body (sent to 'URL+/v1/traces'):

```
{
  "resourceSpans": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "otel.collector",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "test-with-curl"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "instrumentationLibrarySpans": [
        {
          "instrumentationLibrary": {
            "name": "instrumentatron"
          },
          "spans": [
            {
              "traceId": "71699b6fe85982c7c8995ea3d9c95df2",
              "spanId": "3c191d03fa8be065",
              "name": "spanitron",
              "kind": 3,
              "droppedAttributesCount": 0,
              "events": [],
              "droppedEventsCount": 0,
              "status": {
                "code": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

response (200 OK):

```
{
    "partialSuccess": {}
}
```

collector-config.yml

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: collector-config
  namespace: opentelemetry-collector
data:
  collector.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          http:
            cors:
              allowed_origins: "*"
          grpc:
      hostmetrics:
        collection_interval: 10s
        scrapers:
          paging:
            metrics:
              system.paging.utilization:
                enabled: true
          cpu:
            metrics:
              system.cpu.utilization:
                enabled: true
          disk:
          filesystem:
            metrics:
              system.filesystem.utilization:
                enabled: true
          load:
          memory:
          network:
          processes:
      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:
          - job_name: 'otelcol'
            scrape_interval: 10s
            static_configs:
            - targets: ['0.0.0.0:8888']

    processors:
      batch:
        send_batch_max_size: 1000
        send_batch_size: 100
        timeout: 10s

    exporters:
      logging:
        loglevel: debug
      datadog:
        api:
          site: datadoghq.com
          key: ************
          fail_on_invalid_key: true

    service:
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: "debug"
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers: [hostmetrics, otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [datadog]
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [datadog]
```

What does partial Success means? Why my data is not arriving in the Opentelemetry collector?

Comment: Hi @AnyamBorogass have you checked the [official opentelemetry documentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/reference/specification/protocol/otlp/#partial-success) to know about partial success?

Comment: Hi, yes I read the article, but it states, that the response should provide additional information, on what failed etc.. My problem is that I only get an empty object response {"partialSuccess": {}} which has no lead, so I am not sure what is wrong with my config :/

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple questions inside one here, so let's break it down:

> What does partial Success means?

The partial success response from the collector is not a problem. It actually indicates that the request from the OTLP exporter to your back-end was successful.

The partial success response is part of the [OTLP protocol](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/protocol/otlp.md#partial-success-1). It is used to indicate to clients/exporters that *some* data was not accepted by the back-end.

For example, let's say you send 10 spans but only 5 actually got accepted. The rest was dropped for some reason.

The partial success response would help you understand why:

```
rejected_spans: 5
error_message: "Spans dropped due to invalid data"
```

> Why my data is not arriving in the Opentelemetry collector?

The fact that you get a Partial success 200 - OK in the collector means that the collector **did get** data and it exported it. If it didn't, then there would be no export to happen, since there was no data to export.

The question you may be asking is why my data is not arriving **in my back-end**. That could be due to many things, but usually back-ends tend to not ingest duplicated trace/span ids. If you are sending *only* this example from postman, then that is the reason most likely.

If you are sending also real data to the collector and still not seeing them in your back-end, then you can add the Logging exporter to your collector config to ensure the collector is receiving the traces.

PS: The current latest version of the OTLP exporter in the collector is not yet handling partial success responses (it's not doing anything with it, so no logs and such). You can follow this issue to see the progress on it: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/6686

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, newer OTEL collector versions are not very chatty about errors. I guess your problem is old OTLP protocol. Newer versions don't use `instrumentationLibrarySpans` and `instrumentationLibrary`.

You should use OTLP 0.19 (`instrumentationLibrarySpans`->`scopeSpans`, `instrumentationLibrary`->`scope`) + I would say that also `service.name` attribute is useful:

```
{
  "resourceSpans": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "service.name",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "my-test-service"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "scopeSpans": [
        {
          "scope": {
            "name": "instrumentatron"
          },
          "spans": [
            {
              "traceId": "71699b6fe85982c7c8995ea3d9c95df2",
              "spanId": "3c191d03fa8be065",
              "name": "spanitron",
              "kind": 3,
              "droppedAttributesCount": 0,
              "events": [],
              "droppedEventsCount": 0,
              "status": {
                "code": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You will probably still get response `{"partialSuccess": {}}`, but it should go through.

Change was introduced in this version: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/releases/tag/v0.58.0

Comment: How can I use a newer version of OTLP? I am using the latest collector-contrib: v0.69, shouldn't that include the latest OTLP as well? Or should I install a specific older version? @Jan Garay

Comment: @AnyamBorogass that's what I'm saying: OTLP `collector` v0.69 uses OTLP `protocol` v0.19. But your payload is not OTLP protocol v0.19 compliant, because it is using fields from older OTLP protocol. Please note difference: OTLP protocol vs OTLP collector.